# Azure Purge Command not deleting images

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to delete TAGGED images in ACR using the below command. But it says 0 deleted images. There are around 100+ images older than 90 days.

```
Number of deleted tags: 0

$REGISTRY = "MYREGISTRY"
$PURGE_CMD = "acr purge --filter 'MYREPO:.*' --ago 90d "
az acr run --cmd $PURGE_CMD --registry $REGISTRY /dev/null
```

The images in the ACR does have tags

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the container registry*

[image]

*We have to push the image into container registry and while pushing we have to tag the image then only it will show the deleted items*

*The* ***Acr purge*** *container command will deletes the images by tag in a repository that match a name filter and that are older than a specific duration*

*The below example will delete the all image tags before one day*

```
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'image_name:.*' \ --untagged --ago 1d"
az acr run \ --cmd  "$PURGE_CMD" \ --registry <myregistry_name> \ /dev/null
```

[image]

*The below example will take to create a daily schedule ACR task and will delete the images tags and manifest files more than 7 days.*

*I have only one image so it delete one tag image only*

```
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'image_name:.*' \ --ago 7d"
az acr task create --name purgeTask \ --cmd  "$PURGE_CMD" \ --schedule  "0 0 * * *" \ --registry myregistry_name \ --context /dev/null
```

[image]

*For more information use this [Refernce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge)*